Moving local git repo from macOS to external hard drive (APFS case-insensitive) - will there be problems?
I have a local git repo on my M1 Mac Mini (running Sonoma 14.6.1) that I would like to move to an external hard drive (to free up space on my Mac).
The external hard drive drive is new (empty) and has been formatted to APFS (case-insensitive), because I read that this is the best compatibility with Macs (macOS being case-insensitive itself).
I would like to move my local git repo (fullpath is /Users/a/b/c/d) to the external harddrive (fullpath is /Volumes/hDrive).
My best guess so far is to do the following:
mv /Users/a/b/c/d/* mv /Users/a/b/c/d/.* /Volumes/hDrive/

Which would move all files, directories, hidden files, and hidden directories (including .git) to my hard drive. (this suggestion found on https://www.baeldung.com/linux/move-files-hidden-parent)
However, I have read that generally, Git is case-sensitive (because Linux is), and that this might induce problems when moving to a case-insensitive hard drive. However, this directory has only ever been used on my Mac which is case-insensitive and I've never had issues.

Will the command line code I provided above do what I'd like it to do?

Will I run into any problems moving the local git repo from my Mac to a case-insensitive hard drive?



Instead of mv, use cp -R to copy the files to the new drive. That way, you'll always have a copy that you can remove once you ascertained that the repo is working on the new drive. FWIW, this is off-topic for StackOverflow.

You ask this in your question:

“Moving local git repo from macOS to external hard drive (APFS case-insensitive) - will there be problems?”

And you further elabtorte in the body of your question:

“However, I have read that generally, Git is case-sensitive (because Linux is), and that this might induce problems when moving to a case-insensitive hard drive. However, this directory has only ever been used on my Mac which is case-insensitive and I've never had issues.”

If your macOS drive case-insensitive and your new external drive is case-insensitive then there is utterly no concern. The drives are the same and the files are therefore in the same exact state.
That said…
You are absolutely overthinking this.
Why do you want to use the Terminal to do this?
Just run these two commands if you insist on using the Terminal and you should be fine:
mv /Users/a/b/c/d/* /Volumes/hDrive;
mv /Users/a/b/c/d/.* /Volumes/hDrive;


That said, just use the Finder to copy the files.
Git directories and files are just plain directories and files.
But seriously, you can more easily just drag and drop the directories via the Finder. Just open up the /Users/a/b/c/ directory and drag and drop the directories to /Volumes/hDrive.

@Giacomo1968 Thank you for confirming that it would work. I followed your suggestion to simply use Finder to move the files to my hard drive. I have successfully been able to commit and push changes to the files, and all git history looks to have been retained! I had initially thought of using Terminal because I find Terminal provides more fine control over similar types of actions, but in this case it seems it was unnecessary. Thanks!

I think you mean for the command to be:
mv /Users/a/b/c/d/* /Volumes/hDrive

And, yeah, that should work just fine. The issue with moving case-sensitive files is that you might have files with the same name, but different cases. Eg: file1, File1, FiLE1, etc.
While those would be fine on a case-sensitive system, they would all appear the same to a case-insensitive system.
Since you created the git repo on a case-insensitive system (macOS), you wouldn't have any files named the same except for their case. So, the repo would be just fine in both places.
Had you created the repo on an actual case-sensitive system, like Linux, then you'd have to double check that you didn't have any case-only-different files.

My understanding is that the command you suggested above would not move the hidden files (and therefore not move the .git directory?). But was the purpose of this answer to highlight that I should remove the very last / in my command (the / after hDrive)?

@SamNewall, the purpose of my answer was twofold: 1) your command line has a duplicated mv portion, and 2) since both locations are case-insensitive, you'll not have any problems

Thank you. I had copied that line, with the duplicated 'mv' portion, from another site (assuming that they had it correct). Looks like that would be invalid syntax however. I'm still uncertain about whether your command would include the .git directory, because my understanding is that your command would not move hidden files. Am i mistaken?

@SamNewall, you are correct - if you use the /*. If you move the whole directory, it would go, hidden files included. However, using the /* moves just the files - and it would, indeed, skip the hidden files. So, mv /Users/a/b/c/d /Volumes/hDrive would move that d folder into the hDrive with hidden files included. If you did actually want all the files, hidden and not, in the root of the hDrive, then you'd need to use a different command.

@SamNewall, you can definitely try this out as an experiment. Just create a simple set of folders matching your criteria. Put some regular files, dot-files, and dot-folders in there. Then try doing a mv with and without the /* portion, and see what happens. Also, try it within a normal directory and across volumes (such as with your hDrive) to see if there's any different results. It'll help ease your mind for future reference.
